# Difference between shared memory and parcel

Tags: android, shared-memory, parcel

I would like to know the difference between shared memory and the parcel in the Android.

I found that the Parcel are used for sharing data between process in the inter process communication (IPC) level and the shared memory contains data shared between applications. I would like to know when the shared memory and the parcel are used respectively and what kind of data are stored in each location?
Is there a connection between the shared memory and the parcel?

Comment: `"I found that the Parcel are used for sharing data between process in the inter process communication (IPC) level"`, not really, `android.os.Binder`s are used for that and they use `Parcel`s to keep the data

Comment: Tank you for your comment. Yes the binders use the parcel to share data between process but I would like to know when the shared memory is used?

Comment: what class do you mean that supports shared memory? `MemoryFile`?

Comment: CursorWindow and MemoryFile that support Ashmem

Comment: `CursorWindow` has nothing to do with ashmem, `MemoryFile` has no API to be passed between processes

Comment: But I found this:The Android CursorWindow implementation is using Android shared memory (ashmem) and memory mapping feature to store and access text and blob[https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-java-sqlcipher/blob/master/README.md]

Comment: it may use it internally for efficiency but does not provide any public API to use it in inter process communication